# symfony easyadmin new articles are submitted and stored but not the author_id

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm trying since several days to find out how to ask to easyadmin to store the `author_id` (or `user_id` to be specific), but I can't find by myself.

Basicly, by using the `createListQueryBuilder` function in a specific controller to override the easyadmin controller, I found the way to display for each logged user, the articles they created.

Now I'm locked since several days as i dont know how to tell to easyadmin to store the currently logged `author_id` (or user_id),the solution is to get the author_id with `$this->getUser()->getId()` that's ok, but where or how can i link this with my `author_id` before persisting it to the database

For now if i use this code below the author can add manually its author_id but that's not safe:

```
{ property: 'user', type: 'entity', type_options: { class: 'AppBundle\Entity\User' ,multiple: false,expanded: true} }
```

I would like to use an input hidden or any other way that could be more safe

Thank you any anybody could help me

EDIT:it was the hell to find the solution but i finaly found the way to display ONLY THE CURRENT LOGGED USER(who can be a basic admin or contributor if you prefer) or THE FULL LIST OF REGISTERED USERS IN DATABASE if the current logged user as a specific role (in this case that's the website main admin)

here is the solution:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AlterPHP\EasyAdminExtensionBundle\EasyAdminExtensionBundle;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as BaseAdminController;
/**
 * Article controller.
 *
 * @Route("articles")
 */
class ArticlesController extends BaseAdminController 
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="easyadmin")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::indexAction($request);
    }
    public function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
    {
        if(!$this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_DIRECTION_ADMIN'))
            {

                $response =  parent::createListQueryBuilder('Articles', $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
            $response->where('entity.userId = :userId')->setParameter('userId', $this->getUser()->getId());
            return $response;
            }
            $response =  parent::createListQueryBuilder('Articles', $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

            return $response;
    }
    public function createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view)
    {
        $formBuilder = parent::createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view);

        // Here I overwrite field to be disabled
        if(!$this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_DIRECTION_ADMIN'))
        {
            $formBuilder->add('user', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.id = :id')->setParameter('id',$this->getUser()->getId());
                },
            ));
            return $formBuilder;
        }
        $formBuilder->add('user', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.username', 'asc');
            },
        ));


        return $formBuilder;
    }


}
```

1/i created a custom ArticlesController and added 1 method to display the logged user article list if they have a low level role,and display all the website articles if the user role is high

2/ i created a second method which add the currently logged user_id field to the easyadmin formbuilder if the user has a low level role(a contributor for example) OR a full list of users in case the currently logged user is the website main admin

Comment: Can you send us your article class? Seems to be something like `$article->setUser($this->getUser());` before your persist and flush

Comment: Thank you felipe for editing my post making it clearer